# How to track nonprofit donations and sales separately in Google Analytics 4 (GA4)?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have a new GA4 property that I'm using to track several subdomains, including **give.domain.org** and **shop.domain.org**. The previous Universal Analytics (UA) setup included multiple accounts—one for each subdomain. With UA sunsetting in July 2023, I'm working to track all subdomains on one property. Our UA tracking has been pretty simple because our software solutions have had integrations with UA. But GA4 isn't supported by any of our software third parties, so I'm trying to create custom implementations.

My question is, **how can I effectively track both *donations* and *product sales* in the same property?** The recommendation seems to be to use the `purchase` event to track donations, but wouldn't that conflict with product purchases being tracked? It seems like the few resources I've found assume that a nonprofit wouldn't also be selling products.

I'm currently using a custom event called `donate`, and sending a few parameters with that event, including `currency` and `value`. But I don't see any revenue or `value` metrics in GA4.

Is there a way to use the `purchase` event for donations and still differentiate sales and donations? Or is a custom `donate` event the right way to go? Either way, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: Could you use purchase and just pass an additional parameter of "donation" and "sale" for which ever the user is completing? I assume this would give you a dimension to breakout the two.

Comment: This is a great solution! I ended up using the custom donate event, though, to keep a clear delineation. Since I'm using Google Tag Manager, I think my problem was that I didn't create a GTM data layer variable for `value`. After doing that, I was able to see donation values in GA4. Thanks for your help!